# Way to make differential backup from full different but from same database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, backup

I have the following situation:
Our sql server is running in a cloud service. The database to be backed up have 60gb. 
We need to make a local copy of the database for some tests, and it need to be up to date, but 60gb is impracticable to download daily.

We thought to make a full backup, download it one time, make differential backups in following days. Once a week, we can stop the database operations to make the last differential backup from last week full backup and make a full backup, and start again the database operations. In this moment, the local bd, when restored with the last diff backup (made when the db was with stopped operations), have the same data than the last week full backup.

The idea behind this is, if is possible to use the diff backup from last full backup and restore it in our local database. If it is not possible, anyone have some idea of what we can do to get all the data, up to date, from our cloud database?

Comment: Have you done anything to the local copy of the database in the meantime? If so, you're going to have to keep the original full backup around, restore that, and then apply any diffs. So you can do it without re-downloading the initial backup, but you can't do it without *restoring* the original backup.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 in a cloud service? If you have full access to the server (I assume it's a VM?), could you set up log shipping?

Comment: @JonSeigel we have access to the cloud, it is a VM. Can you show some links about this?

Comment: @AaronBertrand can you explain better your idea?

Comment: @EduardoLion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190016%28v=sql.90%29.aspx/css

Comment: @JonSeigel can't figure it out. can you give me a little more help? :D

Comment: The documentation is pretty thorough. If you're having specific problems setting it up, I would recommend asking a new question here with all the relevant details.

Comment: I need to download the full backup (or snapshot) from the cloud service just once (we don't have too much speed in our internet, so we can't download very big files usually), and so i thought to just add new data (this is the problem) since this full backup was made.

Comment: Wait, I missed something. Are the tests being run on the secondary database only reads, or are they reads and writes? A log shipping secondary database would be read-only.

Comment: Thanks for your help Aaron and Jon. We was able to get directly from our cloud provider a full backup of our database in a external hd, and so was able to acomplish the task of making this kind of backup.

Comment: You can try transactional replication with the schedule of every one week sql agent job. You can use transactional replication to take a database snapshot on another server and then every changes on the main server would be replicated on other server as you schedule and agent synchronizes the servers. Also you can just replicate an article like a table and not the whole db.